# Copy TreeView node with object tag

Tags: c#, treeview, clone

I have a `TreeView`. Its `TreeNodes` have a `TreeNode.Tag` property of type `InfoForNode` . It contains field `public DataGridViewRow[] Properties`  where I store all information about node.

Now I want to copy this node (with all its properties from `Node.Tag`) and paste it in the same `TreeView`. I tried to use `TreeNode.Clone()` method:

```
foreach (var node in TreeQuery.SelectedNodes)
            {
                _copiedNodes.Add((TreeNode)node.Clone());
            }
```

It works, but copied and original nodes point at the same instance of `DataGridViewRow[] Properties` (Because its a Reference type and `Clone()` performes a shallow copy of a node).

Please explain, how can I get a proper copy in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to do this manually.

```
        foreach (var node in TreeQuery.SelectedNodes)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = (TreeNode)node.Clone();
            DataGridView[] oldProperties = (DataGridView[])node.Tag;
            DataGridView[] newProperties = new DataGridView[oldProperties.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < oldProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                newProperties[i] = oldProperties[i].Clone(); //or whatever copy method works for this
            }
            _copiedNodes.Add(newNode);
        }
```

This gives you complete control over how you copy the tag data.

Comment: First of all, `DataGridView` doesn't have a `Clone()` method.

Secondly, `TreeNode.Tag` has the following fields: `string Error` , `int Id`, `DataGridView[] Properties`, `string Query`, `int ResultFunction`, `string TableName` and `string Where`.

Therefore `DataGridView[] oldProperties = (DataGridView[])node.Tag` will cause ann error. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: The Treenode accepts a single object to be set.  Therefore you must have a class that includes all these things.  So instead of doing (DataGridView[])node.Tag, do (CustomClass)node.Tag and separate out the datagridview data you want.  If you are just trying to copy row values, then you will have to dig into the datagridview and do that manually too.